# Microsoft services status

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, health-monitoring, health-check

Are there any other Microsoft api that can give service health status of Microsoft?

We are already using api's mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceannouncement-list-healthoverviews?view=graph-rest-1.0&preserve-view=true&tabs=http
But we have observed that status retrieved through this api are updated with some delay.

we are looking for some other options to check if Microsoft services are up or not.

Comment: What is the current delay in your case and what delay do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

There was Office 365 Service Communications API but it's retired and replaced by  Service communications API.

There is no alternative to check health status of Microsoft services.

Resources:

[Office 365 Service Communications API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference)